# "Sign Up" jumps straight to reply url of user flow instead of azure login/register

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, razor-pages, .net-core-3.1

**.net core 3.1 web app with razor pages**

I followed the direction in [setup tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant), [register app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga) and [create user flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows) to try and have users login. In the Azure portal, I can click "run user flow" and everything works great, but once I try it in my web app it does not work.
[azure portal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbZ9C.png)

What happens is when the "sign up" button is pressed it flashes a login URL but then redirects to the reply URL right away (which I have set to jws.ms). Why is it not staying on the login page?

One thing I noticed is that the URL for the login page is different when I click "run user flow" from when I click on "sign up" in the web app. The top URL is the one that is produced when "sign up" is clicked on and does NOT work. The bottom is the URL that is generated from "run user flow" in the azure portal and does work. [urls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/604qC.png)

Here is an image of my appsettings.json for my web app which I believe is to be configured correctly. If I put in an invalid value in any of the areas it comes up with an error when I try to click the "sign up" [appsettings.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElxTp.png)

I have been hitting my head against a wall for a long time, any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Add the reply url of your web app to the b2c app registration. Use the chrome dev tools to take a network trace. You’ll see b2c is returning an error like “this redirect uri is not registered” in the GET request to jwt.ms. Copy and paste that redirect uri into the b2c app registrations list of redirect uris. It will be something like https://my-app.com/signin-oidc